# three things question Discrete math on multipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am wonder about these problem

1.Degree sequence of the complete Multi-partite graph $$K_{n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}, n_{4}, ..., n_{m}}$$

and

2.My class professor said one proposition that
If graph is Eulerian, then graph must be connected.

But in my think, even if graph is Eulerian but not connected example exist...

who is correct??

3.I want to know more precisely definition that Given $x \in V(G)$ the equivalence class of $x$ is connected component.
in this case, equivalence class means graph? set?
and given means for all $x \in V(G)$?  this definition makes me confused...

Comment: Please use MathJax when posting math equations: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, say that your classes are $A_1,\ldots,A_m$, where $\lvert A_i\rvert=n_i$. Note that any $v\in A_1$ is connected to every vertex of $A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_m$; so, what is its degree?  Similarly, every $v\in A_j$ is connected to every vertex of $V\setminus A_j$.

For the second: you are both wrong and both right. If a graph is Eulerian and has no vertices of degree $0$, then it is connected; if it is Eulerian and has vertices of degree $0$, then it is not connected.

For the third: Typically, the connected components are defined as follows:

Let $G=(V,E)$.  We define a relation, $\equiv$, on $V$ as follows: we say that $v\equiv w$ if either $v=w$ or there is a walk in $G$ connecting $v$ and $w$.

It is not hard to prove that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $V$; so, it partitions $V$ in to equivalence classes, $V_1,\ldots,V_k$. These $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ are the vertex sets of the connected components of the graph; depending on your source, you either say that they are the connected components, or that the induced subgraphs of $G$ on these vertex sets are the connected components.